# ASP.NET C# Webservice retrieve data and write to database every n seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, web-services

I'm trying to write a ASP.NET C# webservice that when running connects to an OPC Server (ignore the OPC part for now), retrieves a lot of data and then writes/inserts it into a SQL Database at a set interval.

My webapplication will then allow users to connect to the Database and see the live data that the webservice is continiously writing.

I'm completely new to webservices and I may have "missed the point" with them, but basically I need the service to run in the background and populate the database, so that all the different users can view the data live.

Any ideas on this? I'm completely lost.

Comment: a web service is just a web interface to ask something and get a result all in a well structured way. I guess you just need an application running in background maybe as a windows service.

Comment: I think you want to write a windows service to do the work and a webservice to monitor it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need webservice to insert data in background you can write a windows service to fetch data and insert it in the database.

Webservices are not used for such scenarios. They are totally different things otherwise windows service can be used to do what you want intend to do,

Comment: Yes thanks, what I need is indeed a windows service that takes care of the database data, and my asp.net web app will query the database and present it to the end-user

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to retrieve data from a web service and then store the data in a database. There are a few mechanisms by which you can do this. You can setup a separate application which calls the service. This application can be run at a set interval as a scheduled task.

As far as retrieving the data "live" you can create a web application which utilizes AJAX to keep a web page up to date with the most recent records in the database.